# Ignore report level filter in a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've read numerous posts about this, it still doesn't work for me. My scenario is as below -

I have a Date dimension (DimDate) and a Fact (StockAvailability). There are several visuals on the page and a page level filter that shows data for the last 7 days. However, for one of the visuals, I want the data to be shown for last 3 months, i.e., not limited by 7 days report level filter.

So, I created a measure, clearing up the filter on the StockAvailability using ALL, but that results in a single value for all the dates -

```
Overall Stock Availability = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Availability], ALL('StockAvailability'))
```

Further, I try to re-add the 3-months filter above, but still nothing - I get distinct values this time, but only 7 days worth

```
Overall Stock Availability =
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Availability]),
        ALL('StockAvailability'),
        FILTER(DimDate, [IsLast3Months] = true))
```

How can I Ignore the 7 days report level filter for this given measure?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but in case it's still unresolved. I've just had a very similar issue.

I'm assuming you have a relationship between the StockAvailabilty table and DimDate based on a date column in StockAvailability.

For my issue, I put `ALL(DimDate)` and then apply a `FILTER` to `ALL(StockAvailability[DateColumn])`

```
Overall Stock Availability =
VAR Date3MonthsAgo = EDATE( TODAY(), -3)
RETURN
CALCULATE( 
  AVERAGE( [Availability] ),
  ALL( DimDate ),
  FILTER(
    ALL( StockAvailability[DateColumn] ),
    StockAvailability[DateColumn] >= Date3MonthsAgo
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this isn't working because your `ALL` function is removing the filtering on the `StockAvailability` table but not the `DimDate` table.

In your second measure above, the `DimDate` table is evaluated in the filter context it is being evaluated in, which means the last 7 days filter applies here. To ignore that filter, apply the `ALL` function to `DimDate`.

```
Overall Stock Availability =
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Availability]),
        ALL('StockAvailability'),
        FILTER(ALL(DimDate), [IsLast3Months] = true))
```

Note: I'm not positive you actually want the `ALL('StockAvailability')` part. Try it with and without.

Comment: tried that but still it keeps on applying the report level filter and showing the last 7 days only. Am unable to get last 3 months data to be displayed for this one visual on the page